# Is there a DEX built on top of EOS using smart contracts?

Tags: decentralized-exchange

Have there been developments of a DEX being built on EOS like Ethereum's iDEX? Even though it's still somewhat centralized as is all DEXes, is there anything like Bisq where it's 100% decentralized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [DeltaDex](https://deltadex.io/) manages their exchange via smart contracts, and they made a quick comparison with other DEX-like exchanges on EOS [here](https://deltadex.io/about):

[image]
*Image from the link above*

Although not live, another project worth mentioning is [EOSFinex](https://www.eosfinex.com/), which also appears to aim for a high degree of decentralisation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Alcor DEX](https://alcor.exchange) is fully onchain DEX with orderbook, listing, and matching on contracts.